# Generate notification when Power Automate fails to run a Flow for Desktop

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I have created a flow in Power Automate for Desktop on a server. This flow is scheduled in Power Automate (cloud) to run every hour.

Some times there is an error running the flow on the server side, and I want to get a notification in email each time there is any error.

Image of my cloud flow

[image: 1]

I tried editing the cloud flow, but there no options for what can be done if it fails.